# Java - Determining Whitespace, vowels, digits

Tags: java

I feel like I have the majority of the program done just. I don't believe I truly understand how loops work. I've checked around trying to fix this program, but at this point I don't know where to start.

Update* I guess I wasn't clear exactly what I was doing. Trying to create methods for them individually. Method for digits, method for vowels, etc. I'm fairly new at this, thanks for the help you guys have been giving so far

```
{
  static Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
String s;
int x;

System.out.println("Enter a String(EOF to end)");

s=kb.nextLine();

System.out.println(("You have entered ") + s.length() + ("characters and it contains the following"));

System.out.println(whitespace + ("whitespace characters."));
System.out.println(digits + ("digits."));
System.out.println(letters + ("letters."));
System.out.println(vowels + ("vowels."));
}

public static int whitespace(String s){
int x;
int whitespace = 0;
if (Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(x))){ 
  for containsWhitespace=true{
    whitespace++;}}

return whitespace;}

  public static int digits(String s){
int digits = 0;
int x;
if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(x))){
  return digits ++;}}

  public static int letters(String s){  
int letters = 0;
int x;
if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(x))){
  letters ++;}
return letters;}

public static int vowels(String s){  
int vowels = 0;
int x;
char c = s.charAt(x);
if((c=='a')||(c=='e')||(c=='i')||(c=='o')||(c=='u')||(c=='A')||(c=='E')||(c=='I')||(c=='O')||(c=='U')){
  vowels ++;
}
return vowels;}

public static int length(String s){
for (x=0; x<s.length(); x++) 
{
  x = s.charAt(x);}
}


}
```

Comment: And, what is your question?

Comment: What is the problem to be solved, count of digits, letters and vowels? And what exactly is not working in your case?

Comment: This doesn't even compile.

Comment: So many issues here...

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid `for` loop:

```
for containsWhitespace=true{
  whitespace++;}
}
```

A couple of methods are not returning anything, for example:

```
public static int digits(String s) {
public static int whitespace(String s){
```

Prints are not finding variables because they are not declared.

And I would suggest you to download [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/), [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/) or some other IDE to parse code and provide syntax highlighting, finding errors and warnings will far easier with something that will point them out to you.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is, you need to define 4 static class level variable like:

```
static int whitespace, digits, letters, vowels;
```

And then in all of your method, make it void and expect a character instead of string. So your digit method would be like:

```
public static void digits(char s) {
    if (Character.isDigit(s)) { digits ++;}
}
```

Apply this same logic to all your methods with appropriate counter variable incrementing.

And finally in main method you need to iterate over each and every character in a string like below:

```
for (char ch : s) {
  digits(ch);
  //call other methods as well
}
System.out.println("You have entered " + s.length() + "characters and it contains the following");
System.out.println(whitespace + "whitespace characters.");
System.out.println(digits + "digits.");
System.out.println(letters + "letters.");
System.out.println(vowels + "vowels.");
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem was asked before for which I posted this piece of code:

```
public static void main(String... args)
{
    int answer = 0;
    Scanner input = null;
    do
    {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type a sentence and this program will tell you\nhow many vowels there are (excluding 'y'):");
        String sentence = input.nextLine();

        int vowels = 0;
        String temp = sentence.toUpperCase();
        for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++)
        {
            switch((char)temp.charAt(i))
            {
                case 'A':
                case 'E':
                case 'I':
                case 'O':
                case 'U':
                    vowels++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The sentence: \"" + sentence + "\" has " + vowels + " vowels");
        System.out.print("Would you like to check another phrase in the Vowel Counter? if so Press 1 if not press any other key... ");
        String tempNum = input.next();
        try
        {
            answer = Integer.parseInt(tempNum);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            answer = 0;
        }
        System.out.println();
    } while (answer == 1);
    input.close();
    System.out.println("Have a nice day");
}
```

To count the white spaces, digits, consonants, etc., all you need to do is use the Character class to find out if it is a digit, whitespace, or alphabetic, and the previous code to differentiate between vowels and consonants:

```
public static void main(String... args)
{
    int answer = 0;
    Scanner input = null;
    do
    {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out
                .print("Type a sentence and this program will tell you\nhow many vowels there are (excluding 'y'):");
        String sentence = input.nextLine();

        int vowels = 0;
        int consonants = 0;
        int digits = 0;
        int whitespaces = 0;

        String temp = sentence.toUpperCase();
        for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++)
        {
            char character = (char) temp.charAt(i);
            if(Character.isDigit(character))
            {
                digits++;
            }
            else if(Character.isWhitespace(character))
            {
                whitespaces++;
            }
            else if(Character.isAlphabetic(character))
            {
                switch (character)
                {
                    case 'A':
                    case 'E':
                    case 'I':
                    case 'O':
                    case 'U':
                        vowels++;
                        break;
                    default:
                        consonants++;
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out
                        .println("ERROR: Not an alphanumeric character or a whitespace: '"
                                + character + "'");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The string: \"" + sentence + "\" has "
                + vowels + ((vowels != 1) ? " vowels, " : " vowel, ")
                + digits + ((digits != 1) ? " digits, " : " digit, ")
                + whitespaces
                + ((whitespaces != 1) ? " whitespaces, " : " whitespace, ")
                + consonants
                + ((consonants != 1) ? " consonants. " : " consonant."));
        System.out
                .print("Would you like to check another phrase in the Vowel Counter? if so Press 1 if not press any other key... ");
        String tempNum = input.next();
        try
        {
            answer = Integer.parseInt(tempNum);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            answer = 0;
        }
        System.out.println();
    } while (answer == 1);
    input.close();
    System.out.println("Have a nice day");
}
```

when you input some string like: "dfkl;kg-0sdf903o4k;l5kw34 -0 kdfo0orterl; t34k34l;k5l;34 ", you get the following output:

```
ERROR: Not an alphanumeric character or a whitespace: ';'
ERROR: Not an alphanumeric character or a whitespace: '-'
ERROR: Not an alphanumeric character or a whitespace: ';'
ERROR: Not an alphanumeric character or a whitespace: '-'
ERROR: Not an alphanumeric character or a whitespace: ';'
ERROR: Not an alphanumeric character or a whitespace: ';'
ERROR: Not an alphanumeric character or a whitespace: ';'
The string: "dfkl;kg-0sdf903o4k;l5kw34 -0 kdfo0orterl; t34k34l;k5l;34 " has 4 vowels, 17 digits, 4 whitespaces, 25 consonants.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// counting vowels consonants and blank spaces from a string
import java.util.*;
class VowConsBlank
{
   public static void main(String s[])
   {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a string");
    String str=sc.nextLine();
    int c=0,v=0,b=0;
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
    {
        if("AEIOUaeiou ".indexOf(str.charAt(i))==-1)
           c++;
        else if(str.charAt(i)==' ')
           b++;
        else
           v++;
    }
    System.out.println(" No of vowels: "+v+"\n No. of consonants: "+c+"\n
    No. of blank: "+b);
 }
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer.